# combine multiple ngrx store selections into single call Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I basically need to do 3 calls to my `ngrx` store

So What I had was

```
getUserInfo() {
    this._store.select('userInfo')
       .subscribe(result => this.userInfo = result);
}

getCats() {
    this._store.select('cats')
       .subscribe(result => this.cats = result);
}

getDogs() {
    this._store.select('dogs')
        .subscribe(result => this.dogs = result);
}
```

now I'm trying to condense this into a single method so I tried this

I am importing the rxjs like so

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and this is my method

```
getStoreData() {
    combineLatest(
        this._store.select('userInfo'),
        this._store.select('cats'),
        this._store.select('dogs')
    ).pipe(tap(([userInfo, cats, dogs]) => console.log(userInfo, cats, dogs));
}
```

I am calling my method like so

```
ngOninit() {
   this.getStoreData()
}
```

my issue is the method is being called but I never get the console log?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

**EDIT**

I have also tried

```
getStoreData {
    forkJoin(
      this._store.pipe(select('userInfo')),
      this._store.pipe(select('xberts')),
      this._store.pipe(select('tasks'))
    ).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}
```

but still the same issue, no `console.log()`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you importing `combineLatest()` from `rxjs/operators`. that could be a problem, it should be imported from `rxjs`.

Comment: @delashum nah definitely importing it from rxjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to subscribe. try either this:

```
getStoreData() {
    combineLatest(
        this._store.select('userInfo'),
        this._store.select('cats'),
        this._store.select('dogs')
    ).pipe(filter(e => !e.includes(null)),tap(([userInfo, cats, dogs]) => console.log(userInfo, cats, dogs))
    .subscribe()
}
```

or

```
ngOninit() {
   this.getStoreData().subscribe()
}
```

Comment: Subscribing to the combine latest worked, but its being hit three times, so Im getting `[userInfo, null, null]` then `[userInfo, cats, null]` and then finally `[userInfo, cats, dogs]` Is there a way to prevent this??

Comment: see my edit. i would add a `filter()` to my pipe, something like that.

Comment: You cant includes an array??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes definitely can. i do all the time

Answer (score 0):

You can use forkJoin for your scenario

Example:

```
   forkJoin(
            this.store.pipe(select('userInfo')),
            this.store.pipe(select('cats')),
            this.store.pipe(select('dogs'))
        ).subscribe(res => { });
```

Something like this

```
export const selectUser = createSelector(
    userState,
    state => state.user
);
```

Comment: Please see my updated question, I have done this but Im not getting a `console.log` with the `res`

Comment: Can I see your initial value in reducer ?

Comment: I know these store methods work, since they all work individually - but the initial state is always null, but gets populated through a service call

Comment: Then how you get the data in your index.ts ?

Comment: Not sure what your talking about